# How to bind to topic with Spring AMQP only if exchange exists?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to bind a queue to a topic exchange, but:

1. Only if the topic exists
2. If the topic exists, use the existing settings (e.g. durable, auto-delete, etc)

Reason is, I need a 3rd party application to create the exchange with whatever settings they want to use, I don't want to modify the topic settings.

I put the code below together by reading RabbitMQ Spring AMQP tutorial. It works, but creates an exchange if doesn't exist.

```java
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topic() {
        return new TopicExchange("MyTopicExchange", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("MyQueue").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(TopicExchange topicExchange, Queue queue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(topicExchange).with("purchases.*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the exchange declaration bean and ignore the binding declaration failure.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59994152Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59994152Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("MyQueue").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, AmqpAdmin admin) {
        ((RabbitAdmin) admin).setIgnoreDeclarationExceptions(true);
        return new Binding("MyQueue", DestinationType.QUEUE, "MyTopicExchange", "purchases.*", null);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(CachingConnectionFactory cf) {
        return args -> {
            cf.createConnection();
            cf.destroy();
        };
    }

}
```

If you are not using Spring Boot; set the admin property in the admin bean.

Comment: Is the QueueBuilder necessary here or is it possible to just use the Queue constructor?

Comment: The builder is just for convenience, you don’t have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way by using superclass method setShouldDeclareFalse:

```java
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topic() {
        TopicExchange topicExchange = new TopicExchange("MyTopicExchange", true, false);
        topicExchange.setShouldDeclare(false);
        return topicExchange;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to prevent the creation of the exchange regardless of whether it existed or not on the rabbitmq server. What would happen if you try to bind a non-existing exchange to a queue?